# how to insert data to table using update statement mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need to update a column in my DB, but keeping the existing records and adding to the record more data. I am using the following, but it is not working:

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE products SET imagen =  imagen + \''.$imi.'\' WHERE id = \''.$id.'\'');
```

`$imi` will be abc.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are you sure you are updating a row with existing id (where clause) ?

Comment: yes it replace for zero ando not add the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If imagen is a string and you want to append to it, use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE products SET imagen = CONCAT(imagen, \''.$imi.'\') WHERE id = \''.$id.'\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE products SET imagen = (imagen + \''.$imi.'\') WHERE id = \''.$id.'\'');
```

Hope this works fine.

Comment: Yes, it is truth. I missed the mistace in WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

This query will update imagen column in products table and where id is equal to $id. This query is not for insert new record.

Comment: i want to update imagen without losing de data already inserted

Comment: do you want to append data ?

Comment: yes for example if i have abc i want to add def so it be abcdef

Comment: is **'UPDATE products SET imagen = (imagen + \''.$imi.'\') WHERE id = \''.$id.'\''** working ? I am not sure.